# Android Studio, Java, drawing multiple lines

Tags: java

In a LineView class i tried to declare two arrays of points: pointArrayStart and pointArrayEnd like:

```
private final Point[] pointArrayStart = new Point[12];
private final Point[] pointArrayEnd = new Point[12];
```

In a protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) I initialised the lines like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(pointArrayStart[i].x, pointArrayStart[i].y, pointArrayEnd[i].x, pointArrayEnd[i].y, paint);  }
```

The setters I declared as:

```
public void setPointArrayStart(Point pointArrayStart) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        this.pointArrayStart[i] = pointArrayStart;
    }
}

public void setPointArrayEnd(Point pointArrayEnd) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        this.pointArrayEnd[i] = pointArrayEnd;
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity the lineView class is declared as:

```
private LineView mLineView;
```

in a loop the lines are initialised as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    myLines(100, 100 + (20 * i), 600, 120 + (20 * i));
}
```

I called the LineView class with the code:

```
public void myLines(int e, int f, int g, int h) {
    Point pointArrayStart = new Point(e, f);
    Point pointArrayEnd = new Point(g, h);
    mLineView.setPointArrayStart(pointArrayStart);
    mLineView.setPointArrayEnd(pointArrayEnd);
}
```

But calling the LineView in this way every call overwrites the call before.

How can I call the lineview keeping the lines visible drawed in earlier calls

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. This works:
In the lineviewClass:

```
public class LineView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    int i;
    public LineView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public LineView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public LineView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        for (i=0; i<25; i++) {
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 10*i,255-(10*i),255-(5*i)));
            canvas.drawLine(MainActivity.pointArrayStart[i].x, MainActivity.pointArrayStart[i].y, MainActivity.pointArrayEnd[i].x, MainActivity.pointArrayEnd[i].y, paint);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void setPointArrayStart(Point[] pointArrayStartSet) {
        MainActivity.pointArrayStart[i] = pointArrayStartSet[i];
    }

    public void setPointArrayEnd(Point[] pointArrayEndSet) {
        MainActivity.pointArrayEnd[i] = pointArrayEndSet[i];
    }
}
```

In the mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Point[] pointArrayStart = new Point[100];
    public static Point[] pointArrayEnd = new Point[100];

    int a = 0;
    private LineView mLineView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLineView = findViewById(R.id.lineView);
        for (a = 0; a < 25; a++) {
            meerLijnen(600 + (30 * a), 700 - (20 * a), 50 + (10 * a), 50 + (100 * a));
        }
    }

    public void meerLijnen(int e, int f, int g, int h) {
        pointArrayStart[a] = new Point(e, f);
        pointArrayEnd[a] = new Point(g, h);
        mLineView.setPointArrayStart(new Point[]{pointArrayStart[a]});
        mLineView.setPointArrayEnd(new Point[]{pointArrayEnd[a]});

    }
}
```